# Why standard output does not land in the response but in the error log?

Tags: apache, docker, docker-compose, cgi

I am trying to set up a webhook in my continuous integration system, so that my deployment server can automatically deploy when I push something on my Git.

I did it with a shell script that I made accessible as CGI script with Apache.

That works fine, the only problem is that the standard output from my script gets redirected in the error log instead of the HTTP response...

My script is in a custom folder and I have a symlink like this in `/var/www/cgi-bin`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Nov 29 20:52 deploy -> /srv/myapp/deploy.sh
```

The deploy script contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

base_path="/srv/myapp"

echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""

cd $base_path
sudo docker-compose stop
sudo docker-compose pull
sudo docker-compose up -d
sudo docker system prune -f

exit 0
```

My sudoers file contains:

```
apache ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

And the error log contains:

```
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:31.748772 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: Stopping myapp_http_1_a3ca0bdbd648     ... \r: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:31.749003 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: Stopping myapp_client_1_cb16b60351f0   ... \r: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:31.749151 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: Stopping myapp_server_1_6c148be61c2c   ... \r: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:31.749276 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: Stopping myapp_database_1_2959978817cd ... \r: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:32.532484 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[4A\x1b[2K\rStopping myapp_http_1_a3ca0bdbd648     ... \x1b[32mdone\x1b[0m\r\x1b[4B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:42.705754 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[3A\x1b[2K\rStopping myapp_client_1_cb16b60351f0   ... \x1b[32mdone\x1b[0m\r\x1b[3B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:52.911671 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[2A\x1b[2K\rStopping myapp_server_1_6c148be61c2c   ... \x1b[32mdone\x1b[0m\r\x1b[2B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.105109 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[1A\x1b[2K\rStopping myapp_database_1_2959978817cd ... \x1b[32mdone\x1b[0m\r\x1b[1B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.645366 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: Pulling database ... \r: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.645577 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: Pulling server   ... \r: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.645703 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: Pulling client   ... \r: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.645808 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: Pulling http     ... \r: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.931960 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[2A\x1b[2K\rPulling client   ... pulling from myaccount/myapp\r\x1b[2B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.932480 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[2A\x1b[2K\rPulling client   ... digest: sha256:06202040641b409706...\r\x1b[2B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.932865 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[2A\x1b[2K\rPulling client   ... status: image is up to date for g...\r\x1b[2B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.933561 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[2A\x1b[2K\rPulling client   ... \x1b[32mdone\x1b[0m\r\x1b[2B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.955566 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[4A\x1b[2K\rPulling database ... pulling from myaccount/myapp\r\x1b[4B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.955944 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[4A\x1b[2K\rPulling database ... digest: sha256:c63765a78a26f72ec7...\r\x1b[4B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.956375 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[4A\x1b[2K\rPulling database ... status: image is up to date for g...\r\x1b[4B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.956925 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[4A\x1b[2K\rPulling database ... \x1b[32mdone\x1b[0m\r\x1b[4B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.964085 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[1A\x1b[2K\rPulling http     ... pulling from myaccount/myapp\r\x1b[1B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.964472 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[1A\x1b[2K\rPulling http     ... digest: sha256:4bfc963090f942cba9...\r\x1b[1B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.964782 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[1A\x1b[2K\rPulling http     ... status: image is up to date for g...\r\x1b[1B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:53.965265 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[1A\x1b[2K\rPulling http     ... \x1b[32mdone\x1b[0m\r\x1b[1B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:54.071190 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[3A\x1b[2K\rPulling server   ... pulling from myaccount/myapp\r\x1b[3B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:54.071609 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[3A\x1b[2K\rPulling server   ... digest: sha256:15dcd5ebba6a815342...\r\x1b[3B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:54.071918 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[3A\x1b[2K\rPulling server   ... status: image is up to date for g...\r\x1b[3B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:54.073097 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[3A\x1b[2K\rPulling server   ... \x1b[32mdone\x1b[0m\r\x1b[3B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:54.658070 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: Starting myapp_database_1_2959978817cd ... \r: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:55.416923 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[1A\x1b[2K\rStarting myapp_database_1_2959978817cd ... \x1b[32mdone\x1b[0m\r\x1b[1B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:55.417759 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: Starting myapp_server_1_6c148be61c2c   ... \r: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:55.824527 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[1A\x1b[2K\rStarting myapp_server_1_6c148be61c2c   ... \x1b[32mdone\x1b[0m\r\x1b[1B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:55.825299 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: Starting myapp_client_1_cb16b60351f0   ... \r: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:56.497106 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[1A\x1b[2K\rStarting myapp_client_1_cb16b60351f0   ... \x1b[32mdone\x1b[0m\r\x1b[1B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:56.499781 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: Starting myapp_http_1_a3ca0bdbd648     ... \r: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:57.360969 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: \x1b[1A\x1b[2K\rStarting myapp_http_1_a3ca0bdbd648     ... \x1b[32mdone\x1b[0m\r\x1b[1B: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:57.443070 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: sudo: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:57.443239 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: : : /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:57.443360 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: no tty present and no askpass program specified: /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
[Sun Dec 02 11:01:57.443434 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 25813] [client 12.34.56.78:51316] AH01215: : /var/www/cgi-bin/deploy
```

The HTTP response is completely empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *standard output* was going to *standard error*, the error log would have an entry: `Content-type: text/plain`

Since that's not the case, the docker commands obviously write to *standard error* in the first place. So what you probably want is to redirect *standard error* to *standard output* so it ends up in the browser and not into the error log.

Add the following command towards the top of your script:

```
exec 2>&1
```

It redirects *standard error* to *standard out* for the rest of the script.

If you just want to redirect it for a single command, add it at the end of the command, e.g.:

```
sudo docker-compose pull 2>&1
```

Comment: I can confirm it works, even though I have no idea why docker-compose writes to *standard error*